# Highlighting a ListView item without touching it

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a listView in my application I would like to highlight a listitem without touching it. I would like the first item to always be highlighted. How do I go about doing this ?

Here is my code for my listview:

**EDIT**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listmenu);

        menuList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
    menuList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.id.list_content, heading));
    menuList.setSelection(1);
    View v = menuList.getSelectedView();
v.requestFocus();

 }
```

Comment: [Hint, hint](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png)

Comment: You don't need to have "Android:" at the beginning of every android-related question you ask... that is what the "android" tag is for.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to Android 3.0, the only mechanism you have to do this is to have the selected view take focus.  Try something like:

```
menuList.setSelection(1);
View v = menuList.getSelectedView().requestFocus();
```

You might also try `requstFocusFromTouch()` as well.  In Android 3.0 and later, the **activated** state was added for this purpose, so you can call `setActivated()` on the appropriate view if you are targeting the newer versions.

Comment: I tried that and my app crashed when I went to the listView activity. I have edited my code according to my changes

Comment: in this case try these Lines inside `onAttachedToWindow()` or `onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)` because it seems that your View isn't inflated yet

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listmenu);

    menuList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.id.list_content, heading);
    menuList.setAdapter(adapter);
    menuList.setSelection(1);

    adapter.getView(0, null, menuList).setFocused(true);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest way:

```
getListView().setItemChecked(0, true);
```

What's the next question?!